# Elohim lower than YHWH?

Tags: commentaries, shemos-sacred-names, zohar

The Zohar contains a reference to Elohim as lower than YHWH (vol. 1, 20a), but what does that mean? Could someone explain to me the plain meaning?

Comment: YHWH is the name, it's "Him" while Elohim is His "description", like "one that has powers".

Answer (score 2):

"Plain meaning" is somewhat of a difficult term to use with the Zohar, but here's one attempt.

Nefesh HaChaim in Sha'ar Gimmel at length explains the differences between Elokim and Y-K-V-K. See particularly chapters 10-12. Here's an excerpt:

> זהו ענין ופי' של שם אלקים בעל הכחות כולם. אבל עכ"ז לפי פירושו וענינו של זה השם משמע שיש במציאו גם עולמו' וכחות מחודשים מרצונו הפשוט יתברך שצמצם כבודו והניח מקום כביכול למציאות כחות ועולמות. אלא שהוא יתברך הוא נשמתם ומקור שרש כח חיותם שמקבלים מאתו יתב' שמתפשט ומסתתר בתוכם כביכול. כענין התפשטות הנשמה בגוף האדם. שאף שהיא מתפשטת בכל חלק ונקודה פרטית שבו. עכ"ז לא נוכל לומר שהגוף מתבטל נגדה כאילו אינו במציאות כלל. וכן בכל כח ועולם עליון שמתפשט בכל עצמות הכח והעולם שתחתיו. עכ"ז גם הכח והעולם התחתון ישנו במציאות. והוא כפי אשר מצדנו בענין השגתנו כמש"ל: אבל שם העצם הוי"ה ב"ה מורה על הבחי' והענין כפי אשר הוא מצדו יתברך שנתבאר למעלה

Paraphrased, the name Elokim describes existence from our perspective, in which Hashem is absolutely in charge of everything that exists, but there is a reality to existence. Y-K-V-K, on the other hand, describes Hashem's existence, so to speak, from "His" perspective, in which He is the only existence and there is no reality other than His existence.